# Disallow user to connect from other IPs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I restrict access of a mysql user to just connect from a specific IP? I want to avoid people to connect to my database(s) from external IPs using that specific user.

So, for example, I want user mysql_master to just be able to connect from 192.169.0.10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'mysql_master'@'192.169.0.10';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```